# Нужно в HTML c json вставлять текст

Tags: javascript, json

Есть HTML страницы в которых вместо текста ключ файлов  json(пример {$IN_MAIN2_KUL}). Как используя NOD JS, правильно применить цикл, что бы  заменить контент в HTML.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не знаю что такое NOD, но смею предположить, что Вам необходим движок шаблонов. Благо таких [превеликое](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript) [множество](https://habr.com/ru/post/219873). Использование движков шаблонов потребует изменения HTML, но без этого никак.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде получилось написать код для замены и записи в новый файл:

````
 fs.readFile('de.json', function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
        let arr = data.toString();
        arr = JSON.parse(arr);

fs.readFile('index__main-de.html', function(err, dataHT){
    if (err) throw err;
        let arrHT = dataHT.toString();
            
    for (let i in arr){
        arrHT = arrHT.replace(`{$`+ i + `}`, arr[i]);
        
    };
    fs.writeFile('index-de.html',arrHT, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
    
  })
})


 });```
````